# IntrinsicContentSize is working in iOS 15 but not in iOS 13 and 14

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextview, intrinsic-content-size

I've created a custom TextField because i need a multiline TextField using "invalidateIntrinsicContentSize" to set the size on every change of the text. In iOS 15 it works perfectly, but in iOS 13 and 14 it's not working.

```
    final private class UIKitTextView: UITextView {
    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }
    
    override public var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        get {
            print("Invalidate size")
            return CGSize(width: contentSize.width, height: contentSize.height)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to debug this code, and if i'm using iOS 15, it calls invalidateIntrinsicContentSize, and then it goes inside intrinsicContentSize and set the new size. If i use iOS 13/14, invalidateIntrinsicContentSize is called, but then it doesn't go inside intrinsicContentSize, so the size doesn't change.

Could someone tell me how can i make it work in iOS 13/14?

Thank you for your patience and help!

Comment: Are you trying to get a `UITextView` that sizes its Height to match its text? If so, just disable scrolling.

Comment: If i disable scrolling, my textfield collapse. I'm using swiftui, and i need to do this custom textfield.